# Open MWPhotoBrowser with a link and loop

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I'm fairly new at iOS development so please forgive my ignorance.

I have web view with a search form, sending request to display different pages depending on the search query. When displaying a selected page I want to have a normal html link at the top which will give the user the possibility to display all images available using the very nice MWPhotoBrowser.

So somehow I need to tell Xcode to open MWPhotoBrowser using a link and when this link is pressed send a variable to MWPhotoBrowser and in that viewController somehow loop through a my url.com/variable.

Is this the best way to do this and is it even possible? I have searched as much as possible but I'm not sure what to look for so I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from this [link](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser/issues/11) at github project it should be fine.